# What will be life time of a class if it is containing any static variable and static method

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory, static

My class is containing a static variable and a static method and its memory is not getting release and all the time new object is creating. So my question is, it is because of static members or something else?

Comment: must be something else.

Comment: Can you show the code of this class and sample usage?

Comment: is there any effect of static variable on life cycle of class?

Comment: _"My class is containing a static variable"_ ObjC classes don't have class-level variables. Is this a Swift class? You need to provide [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

An object's lifespan is not affected if it has static variables or static methods. A static method is a method of the entire class. Similarly a static variable is a variable that belongs to the class, not to an instance.

Think of a car factory and a car. A static method is something the car factory does, like build a car. Telling the car factory to build a new car has no effect on cars that were built last year.

Likewise, the calendar on the wall in the car factory (a static variable of the car class) has no impact on cars that were built last year. If you change the calendar in the car factory to show a day from 5 years in the future, it doesn't make the cars built last year suddenly 5 years older.

If your object is not being released it means something is holding a strong reference to it. You may have a retain cycle.